# Rotate each byte in Integer

Tags: bit-shift, bit

Im trying to make a function that rotate each byte in an integer(i got only one bit set in the integer and the last byte isnt used) but im stack this what i got so far

```
private int RotateBytes(int num,int length)
{     
  int mask = 0x00818181;
  mask &= num;
  int newnum = num<<length;

}
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: java,but it doesnt really matter